# PowerBI slicer multi select with AND logic using DAX measures

Tags: powerbi, logic, dax, multi-select, slicers

I have a table in PowerBI which has 3 columns ('Website', ''Feature', 'Feature present?'). My underlying data is called 'Website data'.

Example rows could be:

Facebook   | Follow | Yes

Facebook   | Like   | Yes

Facebook   | Donate | Maybe

JustGiving | Follow | No

JustGiving | Like   | Maybe

JustGiving | Donate | Yes

etc.

I want to add a multi-select slicer but rather than the default OR logic, I need AND logic. I've seen this done using measures in a YouTube video but can't get it to work for my data.

So I want a table visual which only displays services where the 'Feature present?' value equals 'Yes' for ALL of the 'Feature' values selected in the multiselect slicer.

I have 65 'features' (not just the three shown above).

Please can anyone help?

One thought I've had is the following:

Measure 1: Distinct count of 'Feature' to get the total number of Feature selected, as selecting the Features will filter the table to only those Features so the distinct count will be equal to the number selected.

Measure 2: SUMMARIZE table with 'Website' , 'Feature' and ('Feature present?' == 'Yes'). I can then do a COUNTROWS to calculate the number of Features present out of those selected.

The step I am missing is adding a filter where the table should only display the rows where the number of features selected and the number of features present are equal.